# JQuery e alterações 1.12.24

Tags: jquery

Bom dia amigos,

Tenho um codigo JQuery para uma função "subir a pagina", porém não funciona devido a minha versão do Jquery que é 1.12.24 e não tenho como atualizar.

Existe alguma forma de adaptar o codigo com funções aceitas nessa versão? Alguém lembra o que ainda não existia? Segue cod:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.list_options.hotels .hotel_block .rooms_options > .price').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 1000);
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: Qual é o problema que ocorre? Alguma mensagem no console.

Comment: Oi Renan, na verdade não apresenta erro, só não funciona. Eu acredito que seja por causa da versão, já que o codigo em si está correto, e já foi reproduzido externamente.

Comment: Por acaso você **debugou** o código e viu se o evento do **click** está sendo chamado?

Comment: Tenta tirar o evento event.stopPropagation();
acredito que depois disso seu click funcione normalmente

Comment: Procurei nas CDNs e só tem `1.12.2` ou `1.12.4`.. não tem `1.12.24`. Com a `1.12.4` [tudo funciona normalmente](https://jsfiddle.net/5mzoxr0s/). Você precisa especificar melhor

Comment: Isso mesmo 1.12.4 porém não funciona.